# WebBrowser control must reload content every time app page is revisited (Windows Phone 7, Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, browser, windows-phone, mobile-browser

I'm writing an app for Windows Phone 7/Silverlight. When the app is either tombstoned and reactivated while on the app page containing the WebBrowser control (I've saved the Uri in app state) ***or*** that same app page is navigated to by NavigationService.GoBack() or the phone back button, it seems that as long as the control still has the webbrowser.source value, it should then render just fine, but this is not the case. Unless I use the Navigate() method, it shows a white/blank screen, no matter what I try. Unfortunately, using the Navigate() method causes the web content to download again, unnecessarily. It's especially frustrating when only a GoBack() is used to get back to the application page with the WebBrowser control, which is quite frequent in my app.

```
    private void OnWebBrowserLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //webBrowser1.Source = CurrentUri; //does not work, results in white/blank browser page
        webBrowser1.Navigate(CurrentUri); //works, but page has to reload from web, bad UX
    }
```

Any suggestions on a way around this problem? I've also tried putting this same code in the page loaded handler. It behaves in the same poor manner.

I've also tried saving off the HTML (SaveToString) and reloading it from app state (NavigateToString), but the web page does not render completely for some reason, even though the HTML appears fine. Also, I'd like to have access to the Host and Uri properties. I could probably work around that, if I could get the HTML to render OK from NavigateToString. 
Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I believe this is fixed in mango. Even IE itself used to re-load the page if you exited IE and re-opened, whereas now it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You should use browsertask:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

 WebBrowserTask browse = new WebBrowserTask();
            browse.Uri = new Uri(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                //new Uri(URL,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            browse.Show();
```

This should solve your issue.

URL will be the URL of the page you want to visit.